# Making an object dirty and call PersistenceManager.makePersistent multiple times, data won't persist anymore

Tags: java, collections, jdo, datanucleus

I have created a unit test that demonstrates a problem in Datanucleus.
The purpose of this test is to make an object dirty by adding an element to its Set and then make it persistent, multiple times. I have made 3 calls to makePersistent on object A. The 3rd call doesn't actually reflect the changes to the rdbms causing the last assertion to fail.

Dependencies:
org.datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.2.13
org.postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1004-jdbc4

Any help regarding what is going wrong will be appreciated.

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class A
{
    @Persistent(column = "ID", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    @Persistent(table = "A__BS")
    @Element(column = "B")
    @Join(column = "A")
    private Set<B> bs;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<B> getBs()
    {
        return bs;
    }

    public void setBs(Set<B> bs)
    {
        this.bs = bs;
    }

    public void addB(B b)
    {
        if (bs == null)
        {
            bs = new HashSet<>();
        }
        bs.add(b);
    }
}

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class B
{
    @Persistent(column = "ID", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Test1
{
    private static PersistenceManagerFactory pmf;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass()
    {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_CONNECTION_DRIVER_NAME, "org.postgresql.Driver");
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_CONNECTION_URL, "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test");
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_CONNECTION_USER_NAME, "postgres");
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_CONNECTION_PASSWORD, "password");
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_MAPPING, "postgres");
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_PERSISTENCE_MANAGER_FACTORY_CLASS,
                "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory");
        props.put(PropertyNames.PROPERTY_AUTOCREATE_SCHEMA, true);
        props.put(PropertyNames.PROPERTY_DETACH_ON_CLOSE, true);
        props.put(PropertyNames.PROPERTY_DETACH_ALL_ON_COMMIT, true);

        pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(props);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass()
    {
        pmf.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

        B b1 = new B();
        B b2 = new B();
        B b3 = new B();

        b1 = pm.makePersistent(b1);
        b2 = pm.makePersistent(b2);
        b3 = pm.makePersistent(b3);

        A a = new A();
        a.addB(b1);
        a = pm.makePersistent(a);

        a.addB(b2);
        a = pm.makePersistent(a);

        a.addB(b3);
        a = pm.makePersistent(a);

        pm.close();
        pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager(); // Renew pm

        a = pm.getObjectById(A.class, a.getId());

        Assert.assertEquals(3, a.getBs().size()); // Fails. Size is 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure something happens when you make any API call, so look in the log

Comment: Setting datanucleus.DetachAllOnCommit to false will fix it.

I'm still interested to know whether this was an expected and planned behavior by jdo.

Comment: That's what the log is for. Ignore it and you treat everything like some magical black box. Use it and you understand what state an object is in and what is happening

Comment: The reason I've asked this question on stackoverflow was to receive help from those who are knowledgeable about JDO and Datanucleus. I have read logs but it requires some understanding of Datanucleus internals to analyse them. That's why I have posted the code as a standalone unit test so anyone can run and play with it on their own. If you are interested you can also follow the same topic on datanucleus forum at http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,7724